# Website displaying videos and images differently

Tags: html, css

I have a personal website I am using to showcase some tools I have built with short looping videos. Originally I was using images and it worked fine but when I changed it over to videos it has some quirky behaviors. If I have 2 videos and an image it will display but if I make all three into videos they break.

[Working with 2 vids and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyL1t.png)

[Broken with 3 vids](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFEvQ.png)

here is the code with one image working

```
<!----------Portfolio------------->
    <div id="portfolio">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="sub-title">Portfolio</h1>
        <div class="work-list">
          <div class="work">
            <div class="video-container">
              <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                <source src="videos/VendorMap.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            </div>
            <div class="layer">
              <h3>Interactive Geospatial Heat Map</h3>
              <p>
                text
              </p>
              <!--<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i></a>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="work">
            <div class="video-container">
              <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                <source src="videos/VendorMap.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            </div>
            <div class="layer">
              <h3>Bezier Curve Simulation</h3>
              <p>
                text
              </p>
              <a href="https://editor.p5js.org/Pixelfixation/sketches/70X-8B5u6"
                ><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="work">
            <div class="video-container">
              <img src="images/bezier.png">
            </div>
            <div class="layer">
              <h3>Dice Distribution Application</h3>
              <p>
                text
              </p>
              <!--<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i></a>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">To Top</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and then again with just the videos not working

```
<!----------Portfolio------------->
    <div id="portfolio">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="sub-title">Portfolio</h1>
        <div class="work-list">
          <div class="work">
            <div class="video-container">
              <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                <source src="videos/VendorMap.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            </div>
            <div class="layer">
              <h3>Interactive Geospatial Heat Map</h3>
              <p>
                text
              </p>
              <!--<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i></a>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="work">
            <div class="video-container">
              <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
                <source src="videos/VendorMap.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
              </video>
            </div>
            <div class="layer">
              <h3>Bezier Curve Simulation</h3>
              <p>
                text
              </p>
              <a href="https://editor.p5js.org/Pixelfixation/sketches/70X-8B5u6"
                ><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i
              ></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="work">
            <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
              <source src="videos/VendorMap.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <div class="layer">
              <h3>Dice Distribution Application</h3>
              <p>
                text
              </p>
              <!--<a href="#"><i class="fa-solid fa-link"></i></a>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn">To Top</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS for that section of the page

```
/*------------portfolio------------*/
#portfolio {
  padding: 50px 0;
}
.work-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.work {
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.work img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}
.work:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.work video {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.4s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.work:hover video {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.layer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), #1e5dff);
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  transition: height 0.4s;
  z-index: 1;
}
.layer h3 {
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.layer a {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #1e5dff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.work:hover .layer {
  height: 100%;
}
.btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 1px solid #1e5dff;
  padding: 14px 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: background 0.4s;
}
.btn:hover {
  background: #1e5dff;
}
```

I have tried different combinations of playing videos and displaying images. I have checked for console errors but didn't find any.

Do any of you clever web devs have any idea what is going on? I am very new to all of this.

Comment: Have you tried setting a height for the videos? Probably the image is rendered with a specific height and it allows the videos to span the same height when it's present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested here and setting a height to `.video-container` class does the work. You can also set `height: 100%` to `.video` so it looks better.

The issue here is with the `position: absolute` in the `.video` class which removes it from the normal document flow. So, either you have to define a height for it or change its positioning for something different than `absolute`.